# Is Credence Resource Management a scam?

Tags: credit-score, debt, scams, collections

I've been receiving a lot of calls from a debt collector called Credence Resource Management.  These calls are coming from a call center in India.  It seems like this is a scam company.  I did some research and other say the same thing.  http://badfinance.org/review/1420246/credence-resource-management-llc-debt-collection

Is there a way to verify this company is legit?

Comment: Two good answers.  They are required to verify the debt in writing.

Comment: Last time I checked there's no law that says you have to answer your phone or you can't just hang up on someone. If these people want money that they are supposed to be owed they are gonna have to try a little harder than hiring cheap labor to call people cause nobody cares. If the debt was so bad, I'm sure they would find you another way. Or they can keep crying about it forever.

Comment: You can always hang up on someone, you are never required to talk to someone on the phone.

Comment: So this information might be helpful. I received a notice from Credence regarding att uverse account of an outstanding balance, but I never had att uverse account. I called ATT and the representative said the same thing, but I insisted to verify using all my previous addresses. It seems there was an account and it was submitted to credence. I claimed I never owned it because i never did, called credence and they marked it as fraudulent. So i suggest calling the company which reported it to credence and verifying if they actually did that.

Answer (score 17):

We can't really say if any one company is a scam or not here, but we can help you out with general practices to avoid being scammed.

If you're getting calls from any debt collector, the way to find out if they are legitimate is to require them to follow the FDCPA rules.

First, request that they verify the validity of the debt.  Do this in your next communication with them.  They must do so within five days (theoretically of your *first* communication).

Then, you should determine for yourself if you believe that the debt is indeed a valid debt.  If it is not, then you can dispute it, requiring them to cease debt collection attempts until they have verified the debt is valid and provided you evidence.  If you choose to dispute it, do so as soon as possible as you have 30 days from the initial verification above to do so.

If they do verify the debt as valid and furnish you the name of the original creditor, the first thing I would then do is call that creditor and ask:

- Is this account valid (they may or may not be able to tell you)
- Did they sell the debt (they often will tell you this)
- To whom did they sell it

If they say they sold it to a different agency, that may or may not be a red flag; it's possible that agency subcontracted or even sold it to this one.  But at least you could be more confident if they *did* sell it to this company.

Other than that, you just have to use some common sense.  It does sound like this company is towards the bottom of the barrel if they are legitimate, but there are a lot of debt collectors out there and plenty of them are pretty scuzzy but still within the law.  Hold these folks to the letter of the law, and if they don't stick to the FDCPA regulations, call them on it (and perhaps find an attorney to sue them for violations).  They should not call you too often to the point it is harassing, and they should always clearly identify themselves.

Comment: Good answer, and since OP states that he's "getting a lot of calls" I would add that the FDCPA allows you to prohibit a debt collector from contacting you. Notify them in writing via certified mail, and thereafter they cannot call you except in a couple specific circumstances. If the debt is valid and they really want to collect then they can still sue you for it, but they are no longer allowed to nag you about the debt. https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0149-debt-collection

Answer (score 13):

This appears to be a Dallas based collection agency using an Indian call centre to process claims.  If you have no outstanding debt, you might try contacting them directly : [Credence Resource Management website](http://credencerm.com/).  If you scroll down to the bottom of the page, an email address is given for complaints.

As you have noted, a google search for Credence Resource Management yields a serious of complaints including a [class action law suit](https://topclassactions.com/lawsuit-settlements/lawsuit-news/329934-credence-resource-management-sued-failing-stop-robocalls/) concerning robo calls from March of this year.  It may be that they have now changed from robo calls to an offshore call centre.

This company does not appear to be a "scam".  It does appear to be very poorly managed, as indicated by the high number of complaints and the persistent volume of complaints.

Answer (score 1):

I deal with these people and thought they were a scam too. So I called the hospital where the debt is from and they verified for me that they transferred my debt to them and use them to manage other people's debt at the hospital. They call me several times a day, every day and having a phone call with them takes at least 30 minutes, until I am forced to hang up on them. Ultimately, they are a legit company, but are a terrible one at that.